# Replacement for AppModel in Cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-3.0

I would like to implement an autoslug-function for two models in CakePHP3 and use the `beforeSave`-callback for that which works fine. However the slug structure is a bit different than in `Inflector::slug`, so I wrote a small function for the different structure which finally leads to my question

In Cake2 I would have placed this helper function in AppModel which is not existing anymore. What's the best way to do that now? A behaviour (which seems a bit biggish for 2 lines of code) or `class AppTable extends Table` or ..?

Comment: Well, both would do it, and reasons for choosing one over the other are mostly personal preferences and voodoo wisdoms, so the question tends to be a little OT on SO. Personally I'd probably go with a behavior.

Comment: As you would have done in any cake version prior to 3.0 :) See https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/cake3/src/Model/Behavior/SluggedBehavior.php for a 3.0 version by the way.

Comment: Thanks all for answers.. The slug thing was just an example.. I do somewhat miss AppModel, but then again a behavior makes more sense and is probably more lightweight..

Comment: @mark nice indeed! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a behavior and use it where needed instead of putting it in a super model class. If you put that into a plugin and repository you can simply add your plugin as package via composer for every app that needs this plugin.